# Is there a way to get a report of all the words that have been autocorrected on iPhone/OSX?

Tags: autocorrect

I'd like to be able to keep track of both what I originally typed and what I ended up with.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I'm not aware of any way to do this with the stock keyboard.  I've used several 3rd-party keyboards, too, and none of them offered this feature.  That's not to say it's not available anywhere it's just that this is not a common feature.  If you [edit] your question to include missing info (see [ask] for details), it could help you get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just read the "How to Ask" link. Not sure I have much information I have to add to the question I asked, but that may be because I didn't do enough research to have something really specific to ask beforehand. I will attempt to follow these recommendations.